# Table is not found because get_ddl convert table name in UPPERCASE

Tags: python, sql

I am writing a python script using snowflake_python_onnector. The aim is to extract ddls of the existing objects (e.g., tables, pipes, stages) from snowflake to the .sql files on the local computer.

When I run the script, I have the error only with table names which is not in the upper case:

```
query: [SELECT GET_DDL('TABLE', 'PNC_GWCC_12651_RW.**cc_BudgetLine**') script]
2020-08-27 10:25:37 INFO     query execution done
2020-08-27 10:25:37 ERROR    002003 (02000): 01968619-0009-26fe-0000-1c2d074c77e6: SQL compilation error:
Table 'INTE_SDP_LZ_PERS.PNC_GWCC_12651_RW.**CC_BUDGETLINE**' does not exist or not authorized.
```

I put the code below. How can I resolve the issue?

Greetings
Olga

```
OBJECT_LIST_QUERY = """
SELECT seq, catalog_name, schema_name, object_type, object_name, ARGUMENT_SIGNATURE, script
FROM (
    select '01' seq, DATABASE_NAME catalog_name, '*' schema_name, 'DATABASE' object_type, DATABASE_NAME object_name, '' ARGUMENT_SIGNATURE
           , 'CREATE OR REPLACE' || CASE WHEN D.IS_TRANSIENT = 'YES' THEN ' TRANSIENT' ELSE '' END || ' ' ||
           'DATABASE ' || D.DATABASE_NAME || ' ' ||
           '\nDATA_RETENTION_TIME_IN_DAYS = ' || TO_VARCHAR(RETENTION_TIME) ||
           CASE WHEN D.COMMENT IS NULL THEN '' ELSE '\nCOMMENT = ''' || D.COMMENT || '''' END || ';' script
      from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DATABASES D
      WHERE DATABASE_NAME = '{}' 
      UNION ALL
    select '02' seq, catalog_name, schema_name schema_name, 'SCHEMA' object_type, schema_name object_name, '' ARGUMENT_SIGNATURE
           , 'CREATE OR REPLACE' || CASE WHEN S.IS_TRANSIENT = 'YES' THEN ' TRANSIENT' ELSE '' END || ' ' ||
           'SCHEMA ' || S.SCHEMA_NAME || ' ' ||
           CASE WHEN S.IS_MANAGED_ACCESS = 'YES' THEN '\nWITH MANAGED ACCESS' ELSE '' END || ' ' ||
           '\nDATA_RETENTION_TIME_IN_DAYS = ' || TO_VARCHAR(RETENTION_TIME) ||
           CASE WHEN S.COMMENT IS NULL THEN '' ELSE '\nCOMMENT = ''' || S.COMMENT || '''' END || ';' script
      from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA S
      UNION ALL
    select '03' seq, table_catalog catalog_name, TABLE_SCHEMA schema_name, 'TABLE' object_type, TABLE_NAME object_name, '' ARGUMENT_SIGNATURE, '' script
      from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
      WHERE TABLE_TYPE != 'VIEW'
      UNION ALL
    select '04' seq, table_catalog catalog_name, TABLE_SCHEMA schema_name, 'VIEW' object_type, TABLE_NAME object_name, '' ARGUMENT_SIGNATURE, '' script
      from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS 
      WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA != 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA'
      UNION ALL
    select '06' seq, SEQUENCE_catalog catalog_name, SEQUENCE_SCHEMA schema_name, 'SEQUENCE' object_type, SEQUENCE_NAME object_name, '' ARGUMENT_SIGNATURE, '' script
      from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEQUENCES
      UNION ALL
    select '07' seq, FILE_FORMAT_catalog catalog_name, FILE_FORMAT_SCHEMA schema_name, 'FILE_FORMAT' object_type, FILE_FORMAT_NAME object_name, '' ARGUMENT_SIGNATURE, '' script
      from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.FILE_FORMATS
      UNION ALL
    select '08' seq, PIPE_catalog catalog_name, PIPE_SCHEMA schema_name, 'PIPE' object_type, PIPE_NAME object_name, '' ARGUMENT_SIGNATURE, '' script
      from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PIPES 
      UNION ALL
    select '09' seq, FUNCTION_catalog catalog_name, FUNCTION_SCHEMA schema_name, 'FUNCTION' object_type, FUNCTION_NAME object_name, ARGUMENT_SIGNATURE, '' script
      from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.FUNCTIONS 
      UNION ALL
    select '10' seq, PROCEDURE_catalog catalog_name, PROCEDURE_SCHEMA schema_name, 'PROCEDURE' object_type, PROCEDURE_NAME object_name, ARGUMENT_SIGNATURE, '' script
      from "INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."PROCEDURES"
  ) T
ORDER BY seq, catalog_name, schema_name, object_name"""

GET_DDL_QUERY = "SELECT GET_DDL('{}', '{}') script"
```

Comment: You mentioned you are using Snwflake DB. If that is correct, your interpretation of why it is wrong is incorrect because identifiers are case insensitive. `SELECT * FROM PNC_GWCC_12651_RW.cc_BudgetLine` willl work the same as `SELECT * FROM PNC_GWCC_12651_RW.CC_BUDGETLINE`

Comment: is `CC_BUDGETLINE` a view or a table ? is it found in the `INTE_SDP_LZ_PERS `database, in the `PNC_GWCC_12651_RW` schema ?

Comment: Hi @GabrielDurac: PNC_GWCC_12651_RW.cc_BudgetLine is a table. SELECT * FROM PNC_GWCC_12651_RW.CC_BUDGETLINE does not work because it is case sensitive table cc_BudgetLine.

Comment: INTE_SDP_LZ_PERS is a database, PNC_GWCC_12651_RW is a schema

Comment: Try using duble quotes around the table name. SELECT GET_DDL('TABLE', 'PNC_GWCC_12651_RW."cc_BudgetLine"' )

Comment: Cool. I'll just add the answer so people facing the same issue don't have to dig through the comments.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Snowflake applies the following rules for storing identifiers (at creation/definition time) and resolving them (in queries and other SQL statements):

- When an identifier is unquoted, it is stored and resolved in
  uppercase.
- When an identifier is double-quoted, it is stored and
  resolved exactly as entered, including case.

That is why you need to addouble quotes around your table

```
SELECT GET_DDL('TABLE', 'PNC_GWCC_12651_RW."cc_BudgetLine"' )
```